# Creating a page tiled with diagrams, for chess tactical puzzles worksheet

Tags: diagrams, landscape, skak

(This is my first time using StackExchange, please excuse how sloppily this question is phrased)

I am using the skak package to create diagrams/positions for chess puzzles I would like my students to solve- due to my printing budget i need to be as efficient as possible, meaning that I have to fit as many puzzles on each page as possible (printing is charged by the page).
Given that I know I can fit 24, 4cm x 4cm puzzles on a page, while maintaining legibility. How would I go about arranging these diagrams in LaTeX??

Please help, it would really appreciated by myself and the students alike.
I don't even know where to start figuring this out.

[image: an example of how i would like the diagrams to be arranged]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you have a PDF with with all puzzles on separate pages, you could use https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages.

Comment: Please can you provide a minimal working example ( starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This will help in trying to solve your problem.

Comment: You could use a tabular.  TeX is basically an engine for packing boxes inside other boxes.  Note that taublars add 2\tabcolsep spacing between entries.

Answer (score 5):

The actual values depends on your paper sizes but something like this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,pgffor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,landscape,hmargin=0.5cm,vmargin=1cm}
\setchessboard{boardfontsize=0.45cm,marginwidth=4mm}
\begin{document}\centering
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,24} %for the demo to get 24 boards ...
{
\chessboard[setpieces={Ka1,ka3,rc8}] 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]